# Kafka with spark streaming issue: Cannot read data from topic with existing data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to read from a Kafka broker with spark streaming but I am facing some issues.

```
def spark_streaming_from_STABLE_kafka_topic():
    conf = SparkConf().setMaster("spark://antonis-dell:7077").setAppName("Kafka_Spark")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf) 
    sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)

    topic = "stable_topic"
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,
                                    [topic],
                                    {"metadata.broker.list": "my-broker",
                                    "auto.offset.reset": "smallest"},
                                    keyDecoder=lambda x: x,
                                    valueDecoder=lambda x: x
                                    )

    lines = kvs.window(2, 2).map(lambda x: x[1])
    lines.pprint()
    return ssc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate('/home/antonis/Desktop/tmp/checkpoint_v06', lambda: spark_streaming_from_STABLE_kafka_topic())
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Above code does no fetch anything except empty batches:

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2020-05-29 09:32:38
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 2020-05-29 09:32:40
-------------------------------------------
```

Topic `stable_topic` contains a fixed size of data. It does not change.
I have another topic that receives data every second. If I use this topic instead of `stable_topic` and remove the `"auto.offset.reset": "smallest"` then the code fetches data.

I assume that there is something wrong with `{"auto.offset.reset": "smallest"}` but I cannot figure it out.

Does anyone now what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In later versions, `smallest` was replaced by `earliest`. Make sure you check the documentation of the version you are using.

Also, the `auto.offset.reset` configuration will not get into effect, if the Consumer Group has already been consuming some data from the topic `stable_topic`. Therefore, you might consider changing the `group.id` in your streaming job.

If you are assigning a new `group.id`, make sure to set the `auto.offset.reset` to `smalles` (or `earliest` in newer versions).

Comment: it says " Wrong value earliest of auto.offset.reset in ConsumerConfig; Valid values are smallest and largest"

Comment: you mean like this: kafkaParams["group.id"] = "mygroup" ?

Comment: with "auto.offset.reset": "largest" it works, with smallest it does not. I cannot understand why

Comment: it works with "auto.offset.reset": "smallest" and an assigned group.id